# How can I detect when an rxjs subscriber unsubscribes?

Tags: rxjs

I need to run some clean-up code whenever the last subscriber of a subject unsubscribes. How would I do that?

This is what I have so far, but it seems to me to not be a good way of doing it. Surely there is a `reactive` way of doing this?

```
export class TestSubject<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
  protected _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
    const originalSubscription = super._subscribe(subscriber);
    return new TestSubjectSubscription<T>(
      this,
      subscriber,
      originalSubscription,
      (observer) => this.registerUnsubscription(observer));
  }

  private registerUnsubscription(subscriber: Observer<T>) {
  }

}

export class TestSubjectSubscription<T> extends SubjectSubscription<T> {
  constructor(
    subject: TestSubject<T>,
    subscriber: Observer<T>,
    private inner: Subscription,
    private notifyUnsubscribed: (subscriber: Observer<T>) => void) {
    super(subject, subscriber);
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    this.inner.unsubscribe();
    this.notifyUnsubscribed(this.subscriber);
  }
}
```

Comment: The primary use case for subjects is for multicasting. Without knowing what it is you are trying to achieve with the subject, it's difficult to suggest an alternative, but if you are looking for some sort of notification of the last unsubscription, it sounds like the `refCount` method on the `ConnectableObservable` that's returned by `multicast`/`publish` might be of use. `refCount` returns an observable that will unsubscribe from the multicast source when the last subscriber unsubscribes. You'd just need to decide on what the multicast source is.

Answer (score 3):

[`.finally()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/de9f2c8543381ae5f2fa31eb2c9968329ef4fbe0/src/operator/finally.ts) can be used to invoke a callback after the stream completes (error/complete/unsubscribe)

Comment: That's executed on the subscriber when the parent completes, I need it the other way around: I need my subject to execute code when the last subscriber unsubscribes.

Comment: For those using rxjs 6, you'll probably want `finalize` instead, eg. `whatever.pipe(finalize(() => console.log('this fires on success, error and unsubscribe'))).subscribe(() => ...`

Comment: finalize() source code for reference : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/finalize.ts